# Extension for Finding missing semicolon on TS files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Do you know any extension on `VS code` where it detects the missing `semicolon (;)` on the `TS` files? I have tried with [JsHint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.jshint).But it doesn't give any warning.Any other, please?

Line like this(no `;`): `this.detailInformationForm.controls['startdate'].setValue(this.donation.startdate)`

Comment: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/semicolon/, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint

Comment: do you know where should I configure it? @JBNizet

Comment: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/tslint-json/

Comment: I have set it there like this and restart the VS code.But still no warning or nothing.What more should I do? `"semicolon": [
      true,
      "always"
    ]` @JBNizet

Comment: Oh.. It is working.But only on compile-time no? can't we configure it before that like normal syntax error? @JBNizet